# Replacing only NA values in xts object column wise using specific formula

Tags: r, lapply, na, xts

I want to replace NA values in my xts object with formula Beta * Exposure * Index return.
My xts object is suppose Position_SimPnl created below:

```
library(xts)    
df1 <- data.frame(Google = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 500, 600, 700, 800),
                    Apple = c(10, 20,30,40,50,60,70,80),
                    Audi = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                    BMW = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6000,7000,8000),
                    AENA = c(50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57))

Position_SimPnl <- xts(df1, order.by = Sys.Date() - 1:8)
```

For Beta there is a specific dataframe:

```
Beta_table <- data.frame (AENA = c(0.3,0.5,0.6), Apple = c(0.2,0.5,0.8), Google = c(0.1,0.3,0.5), Audi = c(0.4,0.6,0.7), AXP = c(0.5,0.7, 0.9), BMW = c(0.3,0.4, 0.5))
rownames(Beta_table) <- c(".SPX", ".FTSE", ".STOXX")
```

For exposure there is another dataframe:

```
Base <- data.frame (RIC = c("AENA","BMW","Apple","Audi","Google"), Exposure = c(100,200,300,400,500))
```

For Index return there is a xts object (Index_FX_Returns):

```
    df2 <- data.frame(.SPX = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08),
                    .FTSE = c(0.5, 0.4,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.4),
                    .STOXX = c(0.15,0.25,0.35,0.3,0.45,0.55,0.65,0.5))

Index_FX_Returns <- xts(df2,order.by = Sys.Date() - 1:8)
```

Also there is a dataframe which links RIC with Index:

```
RIC_Curr_Ind <- data.frame(RIC = c("AENA", "Apple", "Google", "Audi", "BMW"), Currency = c("EUR.","USD.","USD.","EUR.","EUR."), Index = c(".STOXX",".SPX",".SPX",".FTSE",".FTSE"))
```

What I want is for a particular position of NA value in Position_SimPnl it should look into the column name and get the corresponding index name from RIC_Curr_Ind dataframe and then look for the beta value from Beta_table by matching column name (column name of NA) and row name (index name derived from column name of NA).
Then again by matching the column name from Position_SimPnl with the RIC column from  'Base' dataframe it would extract the corresponding exposure value. 
Then by matching column name from Position_SimPnl with RIC column from RIC_Curr_Ind dataframe, it would get the corresponding index name and from that index name it would look into the column name for xts object Index_FX_Returns and get the corresponding return value for the same date as of the NA value.

After getting the Beta, Exposure and Index return values I want the NA value to be replaced by formula: Beta * Exposure * Index return. Also I want only the NA values in Position_SimPnl to be replaced. the other values should remain as it was previously.I used the following formula for replacing the NA values:

```
do.call(merge, lapply(Position_SimPnl, function(y) {if(is.na(y)){y = (Beta_table[match(RIC_Curr_Ind$Index[match(colnames(y),RIC_Curr_Ind$RIC)],rownames(Beta_table)), match(colnames(y),colnames(Beta_table))]) * (Base$Exposure[match(colnames(y), Base$RIC)]) * (Index_FX_Returns[,RIC_Curr_Ind$Index[match(colnames(y),RIC_Curr_Ind$RIC)]])} else{y}}))
```

However in the output, if a particular column contains NA it is replacing all the values in the column (including which were not NA previously). Also I am getting multiple warning messages like 
"In if (is.na(y)) { ... :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used". 
I think because of this all values of column are getting transformed including non-NA ones. Can anyone suggest how to effectively replace these NA values by the formula mentioned above, keeping the other values same. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Thanks...I have taken your suggestions and edited my question accordingly.

Comment: You need to make a decision of which daily `Beta * Exposure * Index` as there will be three values to replace position NA (since each RIC has 3 indices). Average/median the three? Min/max of three?

Comment: If you see the RIC_Curr_Ind dataframe, each RIC is mapped to only one index out of ".STOXX", ".SPX" or ".FTSE". So there will be only one unique value for Beta*Exposure*Index.

Comment: @Parfait :Thank you very much for your response. This is working. I also wanted to ask if the the same output can be derived from tweaking my code which I mentioned in my post that uses lapply function. My code was working but it was converting all the values of a column (column which contained NAs) including the non-NA ones to Beta * Exposure * Index return

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to combine all data sets to achieve your formula `Beta * Exposure * Index`, consider building a master data frame comprised of all needed components. However, you face two challenges:

- different data types (xts objects and data frame)
- different data formats (*wide* and *long* formats)

For proper merging and calculating, consider converting all data components into data frames and reshaping to long format (i.e., all but `Base` and `RIC_Curr_Ind`). Then, `merge` and calculate with `ifelse` to fill `NA` values. Of course, at the end, you will have to reshape back to wide and convert back to XTS.

**Reshape**

```
# USER-DEFINED METHOD GIVEN THE MULTIPLE CALLS 
proc_transpose <- function(df, col_pick, val_col, time_col) {
  reshape(df, 
          varying = names(df)[col_pick],
          times = names(df)[col_pick], ids = NULL,
          v.names = val_col, timevar = time_col,
          new.row.names = 1:1E4, direction = "long")
}

# POSITIONS
Position_SimPnl_wide_df <- data.frame(date = index(Position_SimPnl), 
                                      coredata(Position_SimPnl))

Position_SimPnl_long_df <- proc_transpose(Position_SimPnl_wide_df, col_pick = -1,
                                          val_col = "Position", time_col = "RIC")

# BETA
Beta_table_long_df <- proc_transpose(transform(Beta_table, Index = row.names(Beta_table)),
                                     col_pick = 1:ncol(Beta_table),
                                     val_col = "Beta", time_col = "RIC")

# INDEX
Index_FX_Returns_wide_df <- data.frame(date = index(Index_FX_Returns),
                                  coredata(Index_FX_Returns))

Index_FX_Returns_long_df <- proc_transpose(Index_FX_Returns_wide_df, col = -1,
                                           val_col = "Index_value", time_col = "Index")
```

**Merge**

```
# CHAIN MERGE
master_df <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by="RIC"), 
                    list(Position_SimPnl_long_df, 
                         Beta_table_long_df, 
                         Base)
                    )

# ADDITIONAL MERGES (NOT INCLUDED IN ABOVE CHAIN DUE TO DIFFERENT by)
master_df <- merge(master_df,
                   Index_FX_Returns_long_df, by=c("Index", "date"))

master_df <- merge(master_df,
                   RIC_Curr_Ind, by=c("Index", "RIC"))
```

**Calculation**

```
# FORMULA: Beta * Exposure * Index 
master_df$Position <- with(master_df, ifelse(is.na(Position),  
                                             Beta * Exposure * Index_value, 
                                             Position))
```

**Final Preparation**

```
# RE-ORDER ROWS AND SUBSET COLS
master_df <- data.frame(with(master_df, master_df[order(RIC, date), 
                                                  c("date", "RIC", "Position")]),
                        row.names = NULL)

# RESHAPE WIDE (REVERSE OF ABOVE)
Position_SimPnl_new <- setNames(reshape(master_df, idvar = "date",
                                        v.names = "Position", timevar = "RIC",
                                        direction = "wide"),
                                c("date", unique(master_df$RIC)))

# CONVERT TO XTS
Position_SimPnl_new <- xts(transform(Position_SimPnl_new, date = NULL),
                           order.by = Position_SimPnl_new$date)

Position_SimPnl_new 

#            AENA Apple Audi  BMW Google
# 2019-11-27   58    80    8 8000  800.0
# 2019-11-28   57    70    7 7000  700.0
# 2019-11-29   56    60    6 6000  600.0
# 2019-11-30   55    50    5   24  500.0
# 2019-12-01   54    40    4   16    2.0
# 2019-12-02   53    30    3   24    1.5
# 2019-12-03   52    20    2   32    1.0
# 2019-12-04   51    10    1   40    0.5
```

Comment: :Thank you very much for your response. This is working. I also wanted to ask if the the same output can be derived from tweaking my code which I mentioned in my post that uses lapply function. My code was working but it was converting all the values of a column (column which contained NAs) including the non-NA ones to Beta*Exposure*Index return.

Comment: Forgive me but I don't recommend your attempted approach for readability, maintainability, and efficiency (as no loop is used here such as `lapply` but vectorized `ifelse`).